# Failed to fork (Cannot allocate memory) gnome-terminal

Tags: memory, gnome-terminal, fork

Running on Debian 10, gnome 3.30.2, I am getting for two days memory errors when trying to open new terminals after some time during the session.

[image: gnome-terminal error]

Reboot does not fix it fore more than a few hours, and diagnostic tools do not help much:

```
$ ulimit -a

core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 95643
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 95643
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

```
$ df -h 

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             12G     0   12G   0% /dev
tmpfs           2.4G   20M  2.4G   1% /run
/dev/sda4       219G   42G  166G  20% /
tmpfs            12G  105M   12G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            12G     0   12G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            12G   21M   12G   1% /tmp
/dev/loop2       65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1513
/dev/loop3      4.4M  4.4M     0 100% /snap/xv/6
/dev/loop1       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1944
/dev/loop5       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10583
/dev/loop0       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1932
/dev/loop4       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10577
/dev/loop6      194M  194M     0 100% /snap/mailspring/488
/dev/loop7       65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
/dev/sda2       144G   43G   96G  31% /media/synthase/VM
/dev/sda1        97G   17G   75G  18% /media/synthase/apps
/dev/sdb3       481G  107G  349G  24% /media/synthase/postDoc
/dev/sdb4       480G   70M  456G   1% /media/synthase/nmr_bruk
/dev/sdb5        72G   37G   32G  54% /media/synthase/phD
/dev/sdb6       2.2T  719G  1.3T  36% /media/synthase/DATA
/dev/sdb2       481G  364G   93G  80% /home
/dev/sdb1       197M  5.1M  192M   3% /boot/efi
tmpfs           2.4G   16K  2.4G   1% /run/user/117
tmpfs           2.4G   80K  2.4G   1% /run/user/1000
```

```
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          23988       15484         617         225        7886        7887
Swap:             0           0           0
```

I mention I have no swap enabled on my system. As I have 24GB RAM, I did not set it up. Note that I had no problem the past three years with this setup.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have this problem on any other program? It sounds like a bug in gnome-terminal.

Comment: No I don't. It is also difficult to say more than "for two days" as it may tend to speculation... And I imagine rebooting should clear all operations possibly triggering the bug. Also, the opened terminals work fine, I just cannot open a new one.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't affect other tools and you've checked that you do indeed have enough memory available, then it sort of has to be a bug in gnome-terminal, right? May I suggest you use `terminator` instead? I find it is a far better terminal anyway.

Comment: just did install it, works fine, looks good, thanks! Will certainly read and alias that one. Still, if there is something freshly corrupted in my gnome-terminal, may be safer to know it :)